# Show logs with condition on process.env.NODE_ENV

Tags: node.js, express, nodeenv

I try to show logs on my ExpressJS app only on the `dev` process environement.

**In package.json :** `set NODE_ENV=dev & node index.js`

**My condition :**

```
server.app.use(function(request, response, next) {
  console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV, typeof process.env.NODE_ENV);
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'dev') {
    console.log(colors.green('URL : ' + request.originalUrl));
  }
  next();
});
```

I'm not passing the condition but as you can see above, I'm on the `dev` environment.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure there is no trailing space? Try `process.env.NODE_ENV.trim()`.

Comment: It was the issue, thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid trailing spaces for environment variables, the parameter can be set in brackets.

i.e.

```
(set NODE_ENV=dev) & node index.js
```

Comment: Thank you it works without `trim()` function.